# Django ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models(eisfiles and AuthPermissionAdd) and and am trying to add **one to many relationship**, as shown in the below code.  But for some reason i am getting " ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'model'. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

```
 class eisfiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    htmlname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meterId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    esiid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    metermultiplier = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    DbName = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='test')
    DbTable = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.htmlname
    def __str__(self):
        return self.DbName
    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class AuthPermissionAdd(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    eisfiles_id = models.ForeignKey(eisfiles)
    temp_id_id_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # print eisfiles_id


    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inne
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "D:\python\project\energy_style\myapp\login\models.py", line 332, in <module>
    class AuthPermissionAdd(models.Model):
  File "D:\python\project\energy_style\myapp\login\models.py", line 338, in AuthPermissionAdd
    print eisfiles_id;
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 842, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 188, in __str__
    model = self.model
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'model'
```

If I remove print statement from model and try to add item, following error is shown

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:9090/admin/login/authpermissionadd/add/

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['login',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rolepermissions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_form.html, error at line 33
   __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)   23 : {% endblock %}
   24 : {% endif %}
   25 : 
   26 : {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
   27 : {% block object-tools %}
   28 : {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
   29 :   <ul class="object-tools">
   30 :     {% block object-tools-items %}
   31 :     <li>
   32 :         {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
   33 :         <a href="{% add_preserved_filters histo ry_url %}" class= "historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
   34 :     </li>
   35 :     {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif %}
   36 :     {% endblock %}
   37 :   </ul>
   38 : {% endif %}{% endif %}
   39 : {% endblock %}
   40 : <form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
   41 : <div>
   42 : {% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1" />{% endif %}
   43 : {% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}" />{% endif %}


Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  174.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  172.                     response = response.render()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  160.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  137.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  206.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  173.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  69.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  209.                 return template.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  197.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  220.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  326.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  992.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  959.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  1049.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_value_in_context
  1026.     value = force_text(value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
  78.                 s = six.text_type(s)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py" in <lambda>
  381.         klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in __str__
  43.         return self.as_widget()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py" in as_widget
  101.         return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py" in render
  291.             'widget': self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs),

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render
  528.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py" in render_options
  554.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __iter__
  1110.             yield self.choice(obj)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in choice
  1117.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in label_from_instance
  1180.         return smart_text(obj)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in smart_text
  42.     return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py" in force_text
  80.                 s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/login/authpermissionadd/add/
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: That's weird. Which Django version are you using?

Comment: As an aside, the recommended approach in Django would be to name the model `EisFile` (CamelCase, singular), and use `eisfile` (without the `_id`) for the foreign key.

Comment: What is this `print eisfiles_id;` thing? The semicolon, I mean

Comment: @nik_m i am checking the what is exact value it is returning

Comment: @Alasdair if I remove print statment, following error shown TypeError at /admin/login/authpermissionadd/add/
__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Comment: Please don't post error messages in the comments - update the question with the *full* traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair updated question, take a look at it please.

Comment: That doesn't look like the full traceback - it doesn't say which `__str__` method is causing the error. If your `AuthPermissionAdd` model has a `__str__` method, please add it.

Comment: @Alasdair updated full stack trace, there is no __str__ method in the model, i have commented all __str__method in model "AuthPermissionAdd"

Comment: That's not the full traceback. It doesn't show where the error is occuring. Look at the **Traceback** section of the error page. Use the *Switch to copy-and-paste view* link and include the results.

Comment: @Alasdair updated Traceback in Question section, please check

Comment: I can't spot what the problem is from the traceback. I don't think that the code that you've posted is enough to explain the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair can you join chat please

Comment: Sorry, I can't do one-to-one chat. I don't think I can help you any further, because the traceback isn't clear in this case, and you haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem. Hope you manage to solve the problem.

Comment: @Alasdair, No problem, but I found why I am getting issue. In the eisfiles model i am using __str__ method, if I comment that it works fine. Please let me know why and how can I use __str__ method without commenting it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if your `__str__` method is returning `None`. Since the `__str__` method returns the result of a `CharField`, that suggests that you have null values in your `CharFields` that contain `None`, which is unusual.

You can either fix up the null values in the database, or change your `__str__` method, for example:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class eisfiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self.address)  # use str() in Python 3
```

Note that if you are using Python 2 and defining `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`, then you should be using the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator`.

In your question, you have three `__str__` methods for the same model. Only the last one will be used, the first two will be ignored.